# Spring Context shutting down camel routes when activemq connection is lost

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have an application using spring-boot, Apache Camel and active MQ. The camel routes are activeMQ queue polling routes.

This is the camel-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Configures the Camel Context-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${envpath}/activemqApplication.properties</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


   <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="${message.sessions.per.connection}"/>
        <property name="maxConnections" value="${message.max.connections}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"   primary="true">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${message.broker.url}"/>
        <property name="trustAllPackages" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="usePooledConnection" value="true"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${activemq.concurrency}" />
    </bean>



<bean id="fileSupport" class=" com.archive.app.module.helper.filesSupport">
</bean>


  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>com.fileSupport.app.routes</package>

  </camelContext>

</beans>
```

These are the classes

Spring boot class

```
package com.fileSupport.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

public final class FileSupportMain {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(FileArchiveSpringBootApplication.class);
        app.setWebEnvironment(false);
        app.run(args);
    }

    private FileSupportMain() {
    }
}
```

Spring boot main class

```
package com.fileSupport.app;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@ImportResource({"classpath:/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties

@SpringBootApplication
public  class FileSupportSpringBootApplication {
}



package com.fileSupport.app.routes;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonLibrary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
```

Camel Routes:

```
/**
 * ActiveMQ queue is watched by
 * this route which then performs content based
 * routing on the messages using XPath.
 */

@Component
public final class ConsumeActiveMQmessages extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {


         from("activemq:queue:" + Variables.RECEIVE_QUEUE1)
             .routeId("queueRoute")

             .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Body: $simple{body}")
             .to("activemq:queue:" + Variables.RECEIVE_QUEUE2);

         from("activemq:queue:" + Variables.RECEIVE_QUEUE2)
         .to("direct:callback");

         from("direct:callback")

         .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "body: $simple{body}")

         .end();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using spring-boot-starter-web you should turn on the Camel run controller option.

See the docs for the option at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelConfigurationProperties.java#L124

You just configure this using normal spring boot configuration style.

Comment: Link in the answer is dead